Asymptotics in the coupon collector's problem
I have read Erdös-Renyi's 1961 paper on the coupon collector's problem where the goal is to have $m$ collections.
They show that the necessary number of coupons $X_n$ is such that $\left(\frac{X_n}n - \log(n) - (m-1)\log(\log(n))\right)_n$ converges towards a Gumbel distribution. The proof is clear. However, they use that result to claim that $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X_n}n - \log(n) - (m-1)\log(\log(n))\right]$ converges towards the mean of the Gumbel. Sounds weird...
I do not manage to fill their gap. The control of the right tail is ok, but not that of the left one. Any idea?
